Is Pirsumei Nissa limited to a specific time?
I'm curious about the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa (publicizing the miracle), which is typically associated with Chanukkah and Purim. My question is: Can this mitzvah be fulfilled at any time of the year, beyond the specific days of these holidays?
For example, if someone were to erect a public menorah in August, would this act fulfill the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa? Would there be a reward for doing so outside the context of Chanukkah?
The question might be more complex when it comes to Purim, as the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa on Purim is primarily fulfilled through the reading of the Megillah. However, could publicizing the miracle of Purim in other ways throughout the year also be considered fulfilling this mitzvah?
In summary, can the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa be observed at any time, or is it only applicable during the specific days of Chanukkah and Purim (or other miracles)?

"I'm curious about the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa (publicizing the miracle)...would this act fulfill the mitzvah of Pirsumei Nisa?" Where do you get that there is an independent commandment of פרסומי ניסא (as opposed to seeing this as a motivating rationale or intended effect of particular miswoth)? " if someone were to erect a public menorah in August.." better yet, ask about lighting it during the daytime on Hanukah.

@Deuteronomy or at nighttime in random park that's not your house

@DoubleAA agreed :)

@Deuteronomy The Rivash (111) gives that, alone, as the reason for lighting the menorah in shul with a berachah.

And @DoubleAA, see Az Nidberu 5:37 and 6:75, who extends the Rivash's point to such public menorah lightings.

@Meir you are aware that making a blessing over a custom is a controversial topic, and surely one cannot build an entire miswa out of an opinion permitting such recitation on a certain occasion?

@Deuteronomy You are aware that the Rivash is a pretty highly regarded halachic authority whose opinion carries great weight? The fact is that his logic about lighting in shul with a berachah is codified as halachah in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 671:7. Now, the OP's question is about whether it can be extended to the rest of the year; I don't know, which is why I didn't write an answer, just a comment. But you asked "Where do you get that there is an independent commandment of פרסומי ניסא," and the answer is that the Rivash considers it just that.

@Meir And see Mi Yodeya Q142560 who extends it even to random lightings anytime ever. You are correct that a few authorities sought to extend the mitzva in this general direction, but the reductio ad absurdum point remains.

You also don't summarize the Rivash well: he says when they light inside at home & don't publicize the miracle, they decided to light in shul too to accomplish the spirit of the mitzva of lighting chanuka candles (and for those who say blessings on minhagim like hallel on rosh chodesh, this would qualify as a time-honored custom). He does not say there's an independent commandment of פרסומי ניסא divorced from lighting at home. (I note historically I know of no evidence of any custom of lighting menoras in random parks or at random times in the summer.)

Here's the text of the Ribhash for anyone else curious to see it inside: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%91%22%D7%A9/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%90
