Can a husband make a bracha on lighting Chanukah candles when away from home?
I understand that there are circumstances in which a husband traveling during Chanukah may rely on his wife lighting candles at home. But suppose the husband chooses to light anyway, in circumstances where his personal fulfillment may be questionable. E.g., suppose he is staying in a hotel, but will light in a Chabad House where he eats. Should he make a bracha given that he can certainly be yotze with his wife's lighting?
It seems to me that we commonly say the brachot over the menorah lighting under other doubtful conditions, e.g., in shul, so maybe the aspect of pirsumei nisa makes this different from other mitzvot, and the brachot are justified in any case. Or maybe the existence of a doubt regarding brachot is a reason specifically not to light candles if one can be yotze through one's wife! Has this question been addressed?

Why is a shul doubtful?

Maybe doubtful isn't the right word. But it's not "ish u'beyto", the situation for which the lighting was instituted.

Yes, there is discussion why lighting in a shul is even a thing. Most assume it's a special rule about shuls and your assumption about what the institution might be somehow imprecise. Chabad assumes it means anyone can light anything anywhere with blessings. See for instance https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/142560/is-pirsumei-nissa-limited-to-a-specific-time#comment475743_142560

How do you know he fulfills his obligation through his wife when he isn't present for the lighting?

@Dude that's the definition of one candle per household. The better question is if the husband still part of the household if he sleeps elsewhere.

The Chayei Adam (154:33) addresses this:

מי שיש לו אשה בביתו ויודע בה בודאי שתדליק פטור מלהדליק ומיהו י"א דעכ"פ חייב לראות את הנרות ולברך שעשה נסים ושהחיינו או שישמע מאחר ויענה אמן וגם י"א דאם ירצה להדליק מותר לו להדליק ולברך ואף לפי דעה זו לפי מה שמבואר לעיל דעיקר זמן הדלקתה הוא רק עד שתכלה רגל וידוע שהנוסעים לירידים נוסעים כמה שעות בלילה ולכן ראוי לכל י"ש להזהיר לאשתו קודם נסיעתו שתהיה זהירה בזה להדליק תיכף בצאת הכוכבים והוא יסמוך עליה ומכל מקום כשיבא לאושפיזא ידליק בלא ברכה ויהדר לשמוע הברכות ממי שחייב להדליק ויענה אמן ואם אין אחר עמו והוא בבית נכרי או שבא לאחד שכבר הדליק שם ידליק ויסמוך על הפוסקים דפטור מלברך ככל דין ספק ברכות להקל.‏

He starts off by mentioning an opinion that the traveler whose wife is lighting for him at home still has an obligation to see Chanuka candles, if possible, and make the 2nd -  שעשה ניסים  - Bracha. On the first night, he also says the first Bracha - שהחיינו.
He then mentions an opinion that if he wants to, he can light his own Chanukia and make all the Brachot.
The Chayei Adam then seems to prefer this solution: His wife lights as early as possible so that the traveler will have fulfilled his obligation by the time he wants to light. Yet he also should light, after hearing the Brachot from somebody who needs to make the Brachot. If no such person is around, then he lights without a Bracha.
